# Play 2.0 - Push current state of execution to page

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

So I currently have an application independent of Play which may take a long time in its execution.

I want to put a UI on top of it using Play where the application may be invoked and to display some of the details of the execution inside of the application to the user. I would like the page to be updated automatically as the execution proceeds e.g. if a variable in the application increments this would be reflected on the page.

I'm not sure where to begin with this - do I need to split the application up into models + controllers ? Or do I just need to have code in a controller to instantiate the classes I have already coded and call the methods I need ?

What about constantly showing the execution state on the page?

Any resources I should know about/read ? Code examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have already done so, but a good starting point is to create a skeleton Play application using the `play new` command, while referring the [creating a new application](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/NewApplication%20%22creating%20a%20new%20application%22%20section.) section. You will have "views" (HTML template pages) and one controller (in `Application.scala`). You could add more controllers, but as you will have just a single page that should suffice.

You can add jars from your app (if it's a JVM app) to the lib directory of your Play application. From this: "Or do I just need to have code in a controller to instantiate the classes I have already coded and call the methods I need?" it sounds like you would be happy to have your app run in the process of the Jetty + Play server. Check out the [Global](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaGlobal) object for starting your app at process startup.

Check out the section on [comet sockets](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaComet) for sending updates from the Play app to the browser. You'll need a bit of Javascript in the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have this application running outside of play, perhaps on another server? Can you modify the application, or is this 3rd party software?

If so, you have to have some way to send data back and forth between your play front end and your application. You can either have your application expose a websocket, and then your play front end and your application can push data back and forth to each other. You can then have your client page have a websocket open to you play front end, and then play can push the updates to the client. If your application can't support a websocket, you could also expose some URLs on your front end for the application to POST to. You can then use some sort of message bus or database mechanism (RabbitMQ, redis, Mongo capped collection, or even just a shared Queue object) so that the front end websocket can get those updates and send them to the client.